# How do I assign Json to Editor in drafjs?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, draftjs

I am getting json object in which I  want to assign text to draftjs editor
but when I try to assign it it throw error

"PageContainer.js:165 Uncaught TypeError: draft_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.EditorState.createFromText is not a function"

```
this.setState({
            editorState2: EditorState.createFromText(ContentState.createFromText("hi"))
         });
```

Editor was already created from constructor with

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editorState1: EditorState.createEmpty(),
            editorState2: EditorState.createEmpty(),
            persons: []

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change **EditorState.createFromText** to **EditorState.createWithContent**

```
this.setState({
    editorState2: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText("hi"))
});
```